# AWS: how to send SMTP email from a web server that has no public IP address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp

I have a web server in an EC2 instance that does not have a public IP address (it is behind an Application Load Balancer). This web server needs to send SMTP emails, but it can't, because it can't access Internet and therefore can't access AWS's SMTP server.

What can I do? I don't want to give the web server a public IP address.

Thanks!

Comment: Need to setup NAT gateway, so that instance in a private subnet could access SES.

Comment: I did. I can browse Internet from that EC2 instance. However, using proven AWS SES credentials, I just can't send email. It always timed out. Why? I am pulling my hair out...

Comment: AWS support found out why. The NAT gateway was obvious in the public subnet, and the network ACL for that public subnet didn't open port 587.

Comment: Good its solved.